# How make visible EasyCap in Java Media Framework (JMF)

Tags: java, camera, jmf

I'm trying to get image frames from an analog cam using EasyCap and Java Media Framework (JMF) on Windows.

The problem is that JMFRegistry do not detect EasyCap, it is not visible as a VFW device on my Windows machine, first step to get frames from my own developed java app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"EasyCap"*  Never heard of it.  Note that JMF will only deal with a 640x480 (maximum) resolution though.  Do web cams still offer such a low resolution?

Comment: I need a low level method to take frames from an analog cam and integrate this in a java application. 640x480 resolution is good enough for my requirements.